# If in Foreach Loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I followed a small tutorial and created a chat for a website. I added some features to it, and now individual chats can be saved but I'm not sure how to place an if statement inside the foreach loop. I would like to do something like this: `if($chat_message->smgs_id != NULL) { something here }` instead of `<a class="save" href="#" id="'.$chat_message->id.'">Save</a>`

```
$chat_messages_html = '<ul style="margin:10px;">';

foreach ($chat_messages->result() as $chat_message)
{
   $chat_messages_html .= '<li>' . $chat_message->smsg_id . '<a class="save" href="#" id="'.$chat_message->id.'">Save</a> | </li>';
}

$chat_messages_html .= '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ternary for the win!

```
$html = '<ul>';
foreach ($arr as $val)
{
  $html .= '<li>'. (NULL !== $val ? 'something' : 'something else') .'</li>';
}
$html .= '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the assignment into parts so you can fit in the condition.

```
$chat_messages_html = '<ul style="margin:10px;">';

foreach ($chat_messages->result() as $chat_message)
{
  $chat_messages_html .= '<li>';
  if ($chat_message->smgs_id != NULL) {
    $chat_messages_html .= '<a class="save" href="#" id="' . $chat_message->id . '">Save</a> | ';
  }
  $chat_messages_html .= '</li>';
}

$chat_messages_html .= '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$chat_messages_html = '<ul style="margin:10px;">';

foreach ($chat_messages->result() as $chat_message)
{
    if ($chat_message->smgs_id != NULL) {
       $chat_messages_html .= '<li>' . $chat_message->smsg_id . '<a class="save" href="#" id="'.$chat_message->id.'">Save</a> | </li>';
       }
}
$chat_messages_html .= '</ul>';
```